# Can't restart httpd.service on CentOS 7 (Apache server)

Tags: linux, centos7, httpd, httpd.conf

I used the command "service httpd restart" on my centOS apache server, and the following error occurred:

> Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service and "journalctl -xe" for details.

How do I solve this error? I tried reinstalling my httpd using the "yum reinstall httpd" command, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use `httpd configtest` to saw the error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. **See "systemctl status httpd.service and "journalctl -xe" for details.**

(empahsis mine)

> How do I solve this error?

1. Read the error message carefully, note that it provides useful information on what to do to gather more information, specifically it mentions 2 commands that you should run

   - **systemctl status httpd.service**
   - **journalctl -xe**
2. Run the commands mentioned in the helpful error message (the latter will likely be most useful) but look at both.
3. Carefully read the contents of the information provided by the commands. It will contain information that you can use to solve the problem.

Comment: Another apache-specific solution is `httpd configtest` which will flag you with any errors in the config that would cause apache to fail to load.

Comment: "Read the error message" *Preposterous!*

Comment: No one who needs to ever reads anything @Sammitch ;)